# SignalR for updating clients on events passed from another Event system

Tags: asp.net, web-services, signalr, publish-subscribe

We have this Pub/Sub system that you subscribe to via a callback mechanism in C# to recieve events from various things that happen within the database. This subscription has a callback signature attached to it that allows for the Pub / Sub system to callback any subscribers it has and notify them of the change on that Callback thread.

We are taking our windows application and migrating it into a web application. In doing so, I need a way to update this Web Application  (The clients) with information from this Pub / Sub. I want to use SignalR, but not sure where to host it. I assume if I host it on the same Web Application as the Client, it won't be able to subscribe to the pubsub due to it not being able to do background threading.
 Currently, I have it in a Console application hosting the SignalR server on a specific port. Obviously this is for testing and not ideal for a larger scale.

My question is.. is it really safe to be hosting SignalR outside of IIS? should I put this in a Windows Service? Web Service somehow? Can it go in a Web Application somehow?